# How to reuse observable list within component Angular 6

Tags: angular, angular2-observables

I want to reuse observable list, trying following but not working:

**this.transactions** is a observable list

```
this.transactions.pipe(
  map(actions => actions.map(t => {
      if (t.type === 1) {

      } else if (t.type === 2) {

      }
    }
  }))
);
```

Object view:

[image]

It's nothing happen, no looping no mapping, Please help.

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: Nothing working, no looping no mapping

Answer (score 0):

The map operator returns a new observable, you need to assign the new observable to a property.

```
transactions$ = this.someService.transactions$;

mappedTransactions$ = this.transactions$.pipe(map(yourMapFunction));
```

Now you have an observable that you can either subscribe to or use in the template with the async pipe. Nothing happens until a subscription happens.

Comment: Can we reuse this observable list in another function in component.ts ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

It is a common pitfall with RXJS for one to not subscribe to their observables. In angular there are two common ways to achieve this.

Async - In the HTML. They ASYNC pipe will subscribe and unsubscribe for you. Additionally the "as" syntax creates a scoped variable that contains the content that your observable emits.

```
<ng-container *ngIf="transactions$ | async as transactions">
  ... interact with your observable data
</ng-container>
```

Subscribe/Unsubscribe - In your code. Add a subscribe call to your observables to have them emit. Side effect - You have to unsubscribe to prevent memory leaks.

```
ngOnInit():void {
    this.tSub = this.someService.transactions$
        .subscribe(successHandler, errorHandler, completeHandler);
}
ngOnDestroy():void {
    this.tSub.unsubscribe()
}
```